# In maven how to create jar where lib is outside?

Tags: maven

How do I configure my pom.xml so that maven generates a jar where the lib folder and all it's jars are a separate folder outside of my generated jar?

Comment: About what kind of `lib` folder are you talking about? Can you elaborate a little bit more...

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is to use :

1. [Maven Jar Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html) to copy your generated jar to a different location you want.
2. [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) to copy your dependent jars to a location that you want.

You need to use the `outputDirectory` property in both the plugins to define the required location where you would like the jars to be copied to, respectively.

Here is an [example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html) of the configuration you would add in your POM.